# Static Factory Methods - return any subtype

Tags: java, effective-java

I'm reading the book Effective Java and Joshua Bloch, in chapter 2, said:

> A third advantage of static factory methods is that, unlike constructors, they can return an object of any subtype of their return type.

I don't understand how to use this concept in practice?

Can someone give me an example?

Comment: @FailingCoder, that's a very high standard you're setting if *Effective Java* doesn't meet it. It may not be possible for a book to go into detail on every piece of wisdom it contains. The author could very well assume that someone interested in more detail may do their own investigation, and I see no problem with somebody enquiring about it here.

Comment: @kaya3 Okay, that's a good point. I made a fast and irrational statement. https://stackify.com/static-factory-methods/ and https://www.baeldung.com/java-constructors-vs-static-factory-methods

Comment: For instance abstract classes can return instances of **non-public** subclasses depending on which factory method you called, or on data you provided. OR something simpler like `EnumSet.noneOf(SomeEnum.class)` - which is not abstract but same mechanisms apply - which depending on amount of values `SomeEnum` holds will return `RegularEnumSet` or `JumboEnumSet`.

Comment: maybe [Arrays.asList](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...)) which returns a `List`; actually it is an instance of a nested class (called `ArrayList` but not the `java.util.ArrayList`)

Comment: @Phesmo. Good example. I had already read about the EnumSet, but  I had not associated with the concept. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**1. Hiding from the client (better encapsulation) of object creation**

Here's an example of a so-called "Simple Factory" (a.k.a. parametrized factory):

```
public class UserFactory {

    public static User newUser(UserEnum type){
        switch (type){
            case ADMIN: return new Admin();
            case STAFF: return new StaffMember();
            case CLIENT: return new Client();
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unsupported user. You input: " + type);
        } 
    }
}
```

The point of encapsulating object creation into a static factory is that the users don't know (and don't care) how an object gets created:

```
// client code - give me an admin object, 
// don't care about the inner details of how it gets constructed
User admin = UserFactory.newUser(ADMIN);
```

**2. Flexibility to swap out implementations without breaking client code**

Consider this static factory method:

```
// swap out with LinkedList later if you like, 
// it won't break the 100 places that invoke this method
public static List<String> getMyList(){
    return new ArrayList<>(); 
}
```

Don't like any of the standard list implementations and you create your own some time later?

```
public class MyMuchBetterList<E> extends AbstractList<E> implements List<E> {

    // implementation
}
```

No problem, you can still swap inside the static factory **without affecting** those using getMyList:

```
public static List<String> getMyList(){
        return new MyMuchBetterList<>(); // compiles and works, subtype of list
    }
```

Comment: This is a good example, because you could start with a single `User` class with a field for their role, and then refactor it into this class hierarchy without changing the static factory method's signature (and hence without changing any of the other code which creates user objects). +1

Answer (score 2):

Consider for example that you want to write your own option type. You could have an interface `MyOption` with two implementing classes, `Present` and `Absent`. Then you might wish to have a static factory method to convert a possibly-null value into a `MyOption` object. It might look like this:

```java
public static <T> MyOption<T> ofNullable(T value) {
    if(value == null) {
        return new Absent<>();
    } else {
        return new Present<>(value);
    }
}
```

Note that the static factory method `MyOption.ofNullable(value)` returns a different class of object depending on the value of the argument. It would be impossible to write a constructor such that `new MyOption<>(value)` had the same behaviour.